# Error in reading pdf file

Tags: pdf, itext

we made one application to read the pdf file and write in Excel.We used iTextSharp.dll.
Application works fine here with windows XP as well as WIndows7.We created this using applicaiton in VB.net in VS2008 version.we have Adobe ReaderX.

But for our customer its not working and it shows error as Unhandled Exception and shows error as 
*filename.pdf not found as file or resource.*

Whats reason for this error message.Customer PC is Windows7 and AdobeReaderX is installed there.

Pls kindly help me.

Answer (score 2):

Random guess? Some directory or filename information is hard-coded into your application. Or the customer is trying to open an incompatible file. Like trying to open a text file with the paint application.